# Program working in Firefox but not chrome due to being blocked by CORS polict (javascript, html & css)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am currently coding frogger and I am working with Chrome. I keep getting an error of:

> Access to Image at 'file:///C:/Users/owner/Desktop/Frog.png' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access

I tried running the code in Firefox and it worked with no errors. I am using `getImageData` as well as image tags, which I think maybe the problem due to cross-origin data. Any fixes?

Answer (score -2):

If it's just for a personal project you can use the Chrome extension to temporarily allows CORS requests found here:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en